# How to make predictions on sliding window?

Tags: time-series, classification, prediction, moving-window

I need help understanding how to construct sliding windows as well as how to perform final prediction. Any help is appreciated!

I have a dataset from sensing data with multiple features aggregated over day (its a multivariate time series data). So for N users, I have F features and R rows representing each day.

[image]

The above table is for a single user. I have many users hence many tables.

On every 10th day, I ask them a survey question. That is my ground truth. I'm now trying to see whether those F sensing features can help me predict the survey outcome.

**Q1. In trying sliding window approach with this problem, how do you think the window should be made?**

Since the survey is being asked on the 10th day, should I roll the time series based on the date the survey was asked (backward rolling)?

For example, should the sliding window be like this (with the y/target value equal to a continuous variable obtained from the survey):

```
|-----|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| Date| Feature 1 |...........| Feature F |
|-----|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| 10  | 23324     |...........|   23      |
|-----|-----------|-----------|-----------|    

|-----|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| Date| Feature 1 |...........| Feature F |
|-----|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| 10  | 23324     |...........|   23      |
|-----|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| 9   | ......... |...........| ......... |
|-----|-----------|-----------|-----------|

|-----|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| Date| Feature 1 |...........| Feature F |
|-----|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| 10  | ......... |...........|...........|
|-----|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| 9   | ......... |...........| ......... |
|-----|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| 8   | ..........|...........| ......... |
|-----|-----------|-----------|-----------|

Going all the way to the first day.

|-----|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| Date| Feature 1 |...........| Feature F |
|-----|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| 10  | ......... |...........|...........|
|-----|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| 9   | ......... |...........| ......... |
|-----|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| 8   | ..........|...........| ......... |
|-----|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|.....| ..........|...........| ......... |
|-----|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|  1  | ..........|...........| ......... |
|-----|-----------|-----------|-----------|
```

Or the other way around where you begin from the first day instead of beginning from 10th day and create sliding windows till you reach the 10th day? I'm not sure if this makes any difference at all - because once I'm done starting with 10, I'll have to take sliding window from 9th day to 1st day, 8th day to 1st day, 7th day to 1st day etc. Or should I just try both the ways and use whichever one that gives me best performance?

**Q2. What about overlapping -- does it make sense?**
Consider we did that for first 10 days -- that was one approach. I take each 10 days separately. But what if I want to treat them as a whole? I have new response from survey in the next 10th day (ie 20th day from start), is it okay for me to take sliding window till the very first day to the beginning (and not just the last 10 days) and use the recent survey response as my target variable?

**Q3. How do you come up with the final value for prediction during testing?**

The ground truth I'm trying to predict is a continuous number calculated from the survey response. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but AFAIK in classification problem, you make predictions over all the sliding windows and use some majority voting technique to get the final class. But, how do you calculate the final prediction in a regression problem? If I had a testing dataset (of a separate user, say), then do I take their sliding window similarly and make predictions on each sliding windows, and then just take average of all predictions made on the sliding windows?

Thank you so much!